# Binding XML file to WPF Treeview

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am trying to build a XML file editor, where I want to add XML file to treeview control, and based on it's nodes and attributes, i have to show editable textboxes or other controls. I serializing and deserializing this xml data to process in someother module.

I am trying to follow this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27809025/5861508) but I cannot get it working, nothing binds with the control. I am fairly new to XAML and MVVM. so any help , suggestion will be really appreciated.

[image: All I am getting is this]

PS: Input is a xml file, so based on your suggestions i am open to bind xml directly to treeview or serialzed classes through MVVM[preffered].

**XML File Structure:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<interlocking xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <signals>
    <signal ref="SignalRef_1">
      <aspectSpeedDependencies>
        <aspectSpeedDependency aspect="REF" vApproach="VApproach" vPass="Vpas">
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
        </aspectSpeedDependency>
        <aspectSpeedDependency aspect="REF" vApproach="VApproach" vPass="Vpas">
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
        </aspectSpeedDependency>
        <aspectSpeedDependency aspect="REF" vApproach="VApproach" vPass="Vpas">
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
        </aspectSpeedDependency>
      </aspectSpeedDependencies>
    </signal>
    <signal ref="SignalRef_1">
      <aspectSpeedDependencies>
        <aspectSpeedDependency aspect="REF" vApproach="VApproach" vPass="Vpas">
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
        </aspectSpeedDependency>
        <aspectSpeedDependency aspect="REF" vApproach="VApproach" vPass="Vpas">
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
        </aspectSpeedDependency>
        <aspectSpeedDependency aspect="REF" vApproach="VApproach" vPass="Vpas">
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
          <targetRef ref="TargetRef" />
        </aspectSpeedDependency>
      </aspectSpeedDependencies>
    </signal>
  </signals>
  <routes>
    <route id="1">
      <start>
        <signalRef ref="pro.Routes.Route.Start.SignalRef.Ref" />
      </start>
      <target>
        <signalRef ref="Target.SingalRef" />
      </target>
      <elements>
        <switchRef>
          <switch ref="Ref" course="Left" />
        </switchRef>
        <levelcrossingRef>
          <levelcrossing ref="Ref" beam="Beam" />
          <levelcrossing ref="Ref" beam="Beam" />
          <levelcrossing ref="Ref" beam="Beam" />
        </levelcrossingRef>
        <trainDetectorRef>
          <trackCircuitBorder ref="Ref" />
          <trackCircuitBorder ref="Ref" />
          <trackCircuitBorder ref="Ref" />
        </trainDetectorRef>
      </elements>
      <flankElements>Flank</flankElements>
      <routePriority rank="1" />
    </route>
  </routes>
</interlocking>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
//using CoreElements.Core.Interlocking;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TreeviewTest.Stck
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void ExecutedLoadXML(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string executableLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string xslLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(executableLocation, "Interlocking.xml");

            XDocument xmlData = XDocument.Load(xslLocation, LoadOptions.None);
            var Interlocking = XmlSerializationHelper.LoadFromXML<Interlocking>(xmlData.ToString());

            var children = new List<Interlocking>();
            children.Add(Interlocking);

            treeView1.ItemsSource = null;
            treeView1.Items.Clear();
            treeView1.ItemsSource = children;
        }

        private void ExecutedSaveXML(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var planList = treeView1.ItemsSource as IList<Interlocking>;
            if (planList != null && planList.Count > 0)
            {
                // Kludge to force pending edits to update
                treeView1.Focus();
                // Replace with actual save code!
                Debug.WriteLine(planList[0].GetXml());
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CustomCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand LoadXMLCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Load XML", "LoadXML", typeof(Window1));

        public static readonly RoutedUICommand SaveXMLCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Save XML", "SaveXML", typeof(Window1));
    }

    public static class XmlSerializationHelper
    {
        public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
        {
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;        // For cosmetic purposes.
                settings.IndentChars = "    "; // For cosmetic purposes.
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                {
                    if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                    {
                        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                    }
                }
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, bool omitNamespace)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            return GetXml(obj, serializer, omitNamespace);
        }

        public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj)
        {
            return GetXml(obj, false);
        }

        public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString)
        {
            return xmlString.LoadFromXML<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
        }

        public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serial)
        {
            T returnValue = default(T);

            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                object result = serial.Deserialize(reader);
                if (result is T)
                {
                    returnValue = (T)result;
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        public static T LoadFromFile<T>(string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    object result = serial.Deserialize(fs);
                    if (result is T)
                    {
                        return (T)result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="Test_Thesis.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:o="clr-namespace:Test_Thesis"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="o:CustomCommands.LoadXMLCommand"  Executed="ExecutedLoadXML"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="o:CustomCommands.SaveXMLCommand" Executed="ExecutedSaveXML"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:Interlocking}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Signals}">
            <TextBlock Text="Interlocking">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:Signals}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Signal}">
            <TextBlock Text="Signal">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >

        <!--<HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:Signal}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AspectSpeedDependencies}">
            <TextBlock Text="Signals">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:AspectSpeedDependencies}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AspectSpeedDependency}">
            <TextBlock Text="AspectSpeedDependencies">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >-->

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:Signal}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AspectSpeedDependencies}">
            <Grid Margin="3" MinWidth="300">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Ref" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Ref, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:AspectSpeedDependencies}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AspectSpeedDependency}">
            <TextBlock Text="AspectSpeedDependencies">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:AspectSpeedDependency}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TargetRef}">

            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" MinWidth="300">
                <StackPanel Height="auto" Width="auto">
                    <TextBlock Text="AspectSpeedDependency:" />

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <TextBlock Text="Aspect:" Margin="1"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Aspect, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="VApproach:" Margin="1"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=VApproach, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="VPass:" Margin="1"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=VPass, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="1"/>
                    </StackPanel>



                        <!--<TextBlock Text="Aspect:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Aspect, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="VApproach:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=VApproach, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="VPass:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=VPass, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>-->



                </StackPanel>

            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate >

        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:TargetRef}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="1" MinWidth="300">
                <Grid Margin="3" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Ref:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Ref, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>



                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate >
```

```
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Command="o:CustomCommands.LoadXMLCommand" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Text}"/>
                <Button Command="o:CustomCommands.SaveXMLCommand" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Text}"/>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <TreeView Margin="3" Name="treeView1">
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TreeView>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**XML C# code**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace TreeviewTest.Stck
{


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "targetRef")]
    public class TargetRef
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "aspectSpeedDependency")]
    public class AspectSpeedDependency
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "targetRef")]
        public List<TargetRef> TargetRef { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "aspect")]
        public string Aspect { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "vApproach")]
        public string VApproach { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "vPass")]
        public string VPass { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "aspectSpeedDependencies")]
    public class AspectSpeedDependencies
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "aspectSpeedDependency")]
        public List<AspectSpeedDependency> AspectSpeedDependency { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "signal")]
    public class Signal
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "aspectSpeedDependencies")]
        public List<AspectSpeedDependencies> AspectSpeedDependencies { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "signals")]
    public class Signals
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "signal")]
        public List<Signal> Signal { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "signalRef")]
    public class SignalRef
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "start")]
    public class Start
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "signalRef")]
        public SignalRef SignalRef { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "target")]
    public class Target
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "signalRef")]
        public SignalRef SignalRef { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "switch")]
    public class Switch
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "course")]
        public string Course { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "switchRef")]
    public class SwitchRef
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "switch")]
        public Switch Switch { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "levelcrossing")]
    public class Levelcrossing
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "beam")]
        public string Beam { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "levelcrossingRef")]
    public class LevelcrossingRef
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "levelcrossing")]
        public List<Levelcrossing> Levelcrossing { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "trackCircuitBorder")]
    public class TrackCircuitBorder
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ref")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "trainDetectorRef")]
    public class TrainDetectorRef
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "trackCircuitBorder")]
        public List<TrackCircuitBorder> TrackCircuitBorder { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "elements")]
    public class Elements
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "switchRef")]
        public SwitchRef SwitchRef { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "levelcrossingRef")]
        public LevelcrossingRef LevelcrossingRef { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "trainDetectorRef")]
        public TrainDetectorRef TrainDetectorRef { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "routePriority")]
    public class RoutePriority
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "rank")]
        public string Rank { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "route")]
    public class Route
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "start")]
        public Start Start { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "target")]
        public Target Target { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "elements")]
        public Elements Elements { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "flankElements")]
        public string FlankElements { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "routePriority")]
        public RoutePriority RoutePriority { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "routes")]
    public class Routes
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "route")]
        public Route Route { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "interlocking")]
    public class Interlocking
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "signals")]
        public List<Signals> Signals { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "routes")]
        public List<Routes> Routes { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

*********UPDATE***********
[image: update]

I am able to populate Signals, but I am not getting how would I will populate the second child , Routes now

*************Update***************

As per @J.H answer using CompositeCollection solved the issue. Save XML Command seems to be throwing exception but, XML is populated in Treeview now.

Comment: What's your question? What's not working?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Kindly read the updated question.
 XML data is not binding with treeview control. I am only getting this one static item in treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class Interlocking, you have:

```
public Signals Signals { get; set; }
```

But it should be:

```
public List<Signals> Signals { get; set; }
```

**Answer to your edit:**

You can only have one item source so I suggest you combine the Signals and Routes into one collection. Change your Interlocking class to this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "interlocking")]
public class Interlocking
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "signals")]
    public List<Signals> Signals { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "routes")]
    public List<Routes> Routes { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }

    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            return new CompositeCollection()
            {
                new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Signals },
                new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Routes }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the new property Children? It combines both Signals and Routes into one collection. You will then need to modify the XAML to use Children for it's ItemSource:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type o:Interlocking}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="Interlocking">
    </TextBlock>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate >
```

And, of course, add the HierarchicalDataTemplate for the Routes type:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type o:Routes}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Route}">
    <TextBlock Text="Route">
    </TextBlock>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate >
```

FYI - this solution came from:

[WPF Treeview Databinding Hierarchal Data with mixed types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673173/wpf-treeview-databinding-hierarchal-data-with-mixed-types/3673232#3673232)

Comment: Thanks , I managed to get Routes in the Treeview, but "Routes" are still missing. I tried to make another HierarchicalDataTemplate but that doesn't yield anything. 

Do I have to make another treeview or can I still bind "Route" and "Signal" both in single Treeview?

PS: I updated question with xaml and picture

Comment: I was thinking something on these lines, although i am not sure how these classes will turn into xmI when i will save the file. but I am getting Route as Children now. I will try to bind Route child according to this now. and update if something goes south. You saved me from a serious headache Sir :)

Comment: @Shahzad - put an XmlIgnore attribute on Children if needed. I'm happy to help, and save you a headache.

Comment: Finally all elements are in treeview :D 
getting problem saving back the editing values to xml but i am not sure if I should ask a new question or here.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question. If I get a minute, I'll look for the question but no promises... I'm in the middle of writing my own wpf app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230900/xmlnsxsi-is-a-duplicate-attribute-name