# Adding/removing child nodes from xml bounded wpf treeview

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147725/binding-xml-file-to-wpf-treeview/39149060?noredirect=1#comment65797734_39149060) and successfully loaded a xml file to tree view. but is it possible to add a (+)/(-) button after each nodes, so we can add more child under nodes at run time? is it possible to do it while xml file is directly binded as data template or do i have to change my approach to something code based like MVVM?

Comment: I keep on seeing similar issues with linking a treeview to an xml document.  There is no built in method that keeps track of the treeview rows with the elements and attributes in the xml document.  You have to create a dictionary (or similar list) to keep track between the two objects (treeview and xml).  Once you link the treeview to the xml document then you can can easily add items to the treeview and also add to the xml document.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit or point me toward some literature so i can try that? Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen a solution.  It is not hard to create a table of treeview rows to xml elements.